# How to convert SFTP byte payload to java in dataweave

Tags: java, mule, byte, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to convert SFTP byte payload to java using dataweave so I can loop through the input records using an existing flow.  How do I do this?

I have set it to java in Dataweave and preview shoulds the correct output but when I run it it is a byte and I transform to e.g. String before the Transform message connector it remains as a string after the transform message connector too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp" xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="${host}" port="${userprocess.port}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"></http:request-config>
    <sftp:connector name="SFTP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SFTP" pollingFrequency="1000000"/>
    <flow name="userexperienceFlow" >
        <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP" host="localhost" port="2222" path="//input" user="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="2222" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP" connector-ref="SFTP" password="${ftp.password}" path="//output" user="${ftp.user}" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename+'.processed']"/>  
    </flow>
</mule>
```

CSV file

```
UserId,UserStatus
ON1234,active
ON1235,active
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to log message as `#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]` instead of `#[payload]`.

Also add `<dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv" />` line before this `<dw:set-payload>`

Hope this helps.